# How do I Run Accordion Elements on Inline?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jsfiddle

I'm building a simple home webpage for my school to use. I'd like to make it simple and clean, so I'm using jQuery accordion boxes to contain the links. I have the accordion elements working fine, but they aren't properly placed. I want the 'Teacher Links' and 'Library Info' boxes to be placed on the same line, but I can't seem to get it to work. I can't run them with 'absolute' positioning, as that prevents them from extending the webpage when they're opened.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<body style="background-color: #D9F3FD">
<div id="bodyWrapper">
<p class="style1"><span class="style4" id="PHHS">PHHS</span> Home Screen</p>
    <div class="accordionWrapper">
        <div id="accordionStudents">
            <h1>Student Links</h1>
                <div>
                    <table border-color="white" id="table1">
                        <tr id="table1Row1">
                            <td class="table1Row1Data1">Bell Schedule</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">TeacherEase</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">Powerschool</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">Library Information</td>
                        <tr>
                        <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Link</td>
                        <td>Link</td>
                        <td>Link</td>
                        <td>Link</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="accordionWrapper">
    <div id="accordionTeachers">
        <h1>Teacher Links</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Test Teacher Text</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 <div class="accordionWrapper">
   <div id="accordionLibrary">
        <h1>PHHS Library Information</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Text Library Text</p>
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    </div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPXg9/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to address the first problem of boxes being "on the same line", you can just float the elements like that:

```
#accordionTeachers{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#accordionLibrary{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

You also do not need the `.accordionWrapper` around them in your html.
Now for the second point

> prevents them from extending the webpage

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. However if you want the open accordion to extend the colored div (#D9F3FD) you will have to adjust the height, probably to `height: auto;`

In general you should not use `<br> or <br />` or empty table-rows just to create the empty space between your elements. Use `margin-top and margin-bottom` to distance them vertically.

Comment: This solved both of my issues, including the one regarding the extension of the webpage. To clarify, my issue was that the accordion is supposed to extend the length of the background so the drop-down menu doesn't overflow the container, making the box look as if it had a great z-index value (therefore overlapping other elements). I removed the `<br>` tags and used the margin tools as you suggested, and I'm getting better functionality out of it now. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote, but if I did, I surely would. Thanks again!